# Toggle boolean using function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a single function to toggle any boolean of my code, but I'm not able to get the expected result :

```
function toggle(x){
  x=!x;
}
var test=false;
toggle(test);
alert(test);
```

Why doesn't this return `true` ?

Comment: inside of `function toggle(x)` you're setting the local variable `x` to `!x` (and this local variable is gone after the method ends). Booleans, in most languages, are simple types, not objects or references

Comment: You realise anywhere in code where you called `toggle(x)` would be shorter to just write `!x` - which does the job of negating a boolean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Boolean datatype is passed by value.** So, any changes made to the argument `x` will not reflect the actual variable `test`. You need to return the updated value from the function and assign it back to the variable.

```
function toggle(x) {
    return !x;          // Return negated value
}

var test = false;
test = toggle(test);    // Assign the updated value back to the variable
alert(test);
```

But, as said in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683912/toggle-boolean-using-function#comment62845012_37683912), it's better to use

```
test = !test;
```

Comment: *All* types are passed by value in JavaScript. The value, when referring to objects, is an object reference, but it's still passed by value.